# Losing a day when converting a Gregorian date to Um al Qura

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-2.0

I am having an issue when getting the day, month and year components of a C# DateTime object using the Um al Qura calendar.

The snippet of code is:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 6, 24);
UmAlQuraCalendar umAlQuraCalendar = new UmAlQuraCalendar();
int year = umAlQuraCalendar.GetYear(date);
int month = umAlQuraCalendar.GetMonth(date);
int day = umAlQuraCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(date);
```

After running this, year is 1434 and month is 8, which are both correct. However, day is 14 which is wrong (according to here: http://www.al-habib.info/islamic-calendar/islamic-calendar-ummulqura-2013.htm)

If I change the code to:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 6, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1); // i.e. One millisecond after midnight
UmAlQuraCalendar umAlQuraCalendar = new UmAlQuraCalendar();
int year = umAlQuraCalendar.GetYear(date);
int month = umAlQuraCalendar.GetMonth(date);
int day = umAlQuraCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(date);
```

Then day is 15, which is correct.

To make matters weirder, this code is in the depths of a large application: the C# code is called from a VB6 exe.

If I extract the first snippet above to a standalone C# project (.NET 2.0), then day is 15, which is correct.

I've checked everything I can think of that might be different between the two projects: .NET version, Platform target (x86), but can't see anything obvious.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Always you can adjust the hijri calendar as the calculations sometimes are not accurate, when the computer says tomorrow isn't the 1st of Ramadan and people see the moon at the end of the day then the calculations will change to synchronize the actual calendar, the hijri calendar wasn't supposed to be calculated by equations, it is calculated by the appearance of the moon. in the control panel in the regional and language settings if you choose the hijri calendar you can set the adjustment of the hijri day

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding of the Hijri calendar, but I'm using the Um al Qura calendar (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.umalquracalendar(v=vs.80).aspx), which doesn't have an adjustment factor.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 6, 24);
UmAlQuraCalendar umAlQuraCalendar = new UmAlQuraCalendar();

int year = umAlQuraCalendar.GetYear(date);
int month = umAlQuraCalendar.GetMonth(date);
int day = umAlQuraCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(date);

Log.Info(string.Format("{0} / {1} / {2}", year, month, day));
```

In .NET 4.5 and I get `1434 / 8 / 15` as the answer. So it seems that it is a bug in .NET 2.0.

Also check if `umAlQuraCalendar.AlgorithmType` is `LunarCalendar` (It should be so). Because if it is `LunisolarCalendar`, there maybe some minor differences like this.

Comment: Yes, in both cases `umAlQuraCalendar.AlgorithmType` is `LunarCalendar`. I'm just confused as to why it works correctly in a standalone .NET 2.0 project. It makes me think it's something in my app, rather than a .NET 2.0 bug

Comment: Also I remember something vaguely from my VB6 days that it had a problem with `time`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to use configuration value +1 or -1 Day, then add this value to calculated date to correct it.